# The check image doesn't show on the item of Gridview?

Tags: android, gridview

I try to implement the multiple choose on the `Gridview`.

And when I choose the item on the `Gridview` , the check image does not show on the item.

But the `getCheckedItemCount` has add this item. I believe the item has been choose.

But I don't know why the check image doesn't show on the item.

The following is in Fragment.

```
    public class FileBrowserFragment extends Fragment implements MultiChoiceModeListener{

        private GridView fileListView;
        private Map<Integer, Boolean> mSelectMap = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
        private ArrayList<FileNode> mFileList = new ArrayList<FileNode>() ;
        private FileListAdapter mFileListAdapter ;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.browser, container, false) ;

            mFileListAdapter = new FileListAdapter(inflater, mFileList) ;

            mFileListAdapter.GridAdapter(getActivity());

            fileListView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.browserList) ;
            fileListView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            fileListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener((MultiChoiceModeListener) this);    
            fileListView.setNumColumns(3);

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub       
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mFileListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                long id, boolean checked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(TAG, "position = " + position);
            Log.i(TAG, "checked = " + checked);
            mSelectMap.put(position, checked);
            mode.invalidate();

        }

        public class FileListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            private Context mContext;
            private LayoutInflater mInflater ;
            private ArrayList<FileNode> mFileList ;
            private static final String TAG = "MJPEG Player" ;

            public FileListAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, ArrayList<FileNode> fileList) {             
                mInflater = inflater ;
                mFileList = fileList ;          
            }

            public void GridAdapter(Context ctx) {
                mContext = ctx;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {     
                return mFileList == null ? 0 : mFileList.size() ;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {   
                return mFileList == null ? null : mFileList.get(position) ; 
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position ;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                ViewTag viewTag ;
                if (convertView == null) {

LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.filelist_row, null) ;

                    viewTag = new ViewTag(mContext , (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fileListThumbnail) , mFileList.get(position));
                    convertView.setTag(viewTag) ;
                } else {
                    viewTag = (ViewTag) convertView.getTag() ;

                }

                viewTag.mFileNode = mFileList.get(position) ;
                viewTag.setChecked(mSelectMap.get(position) == null ? false : mSelectMap.get(position));
                Log.i(TAG, "mSelectMap.get(position) = " + mSelectMap.get(position));

                return convertView ;
            }


        }

    }
```

And the following of class ViewTag is help to set the check state

```
public class ViewTag extends RelativeLayout implements Checkable{

    private static final String TAG = "MJPEG Player" ;
    ImageView mThumbnail ;
    private Context mContext;
    private ImageView mImgView = null;
    private ImageView mSecletView = null;
    private boolean mChecked;

    AsyncTask<ViewTag, Integer, Bitmap> mThumbnailTask ;

    FileNode mFileNode ;

    public ViewTag(Context context, ImageView thumbnail, FileNode fileNode) {
        this(context, null, 0, thumbnail, fileNode);
    }

    public ViewTag(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, ImageView thumbnail, FileNode fileNode) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mContext = context;
        LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, this);
        mImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_view);
        mSecletView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.select);
        mThumbnail = thumbnail ;
        mFileNode = fileNode ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "isChecked");
        return mChecked;

    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mChecked = checked;
        mSecletView.setVisibility(checked ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        Log.i(TAG, "setChecked = " + mChecked);
    }


    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setChecked(!mChecked);
        Log.i(TAG, "toggle");
    }


}
```

The `id` of `check imageview` is `select` and in `grid_item.xml`.

The item of `Gridview` is call `fileListThumbnail` and in `filelist_row.xml`.

And `id` of the `GridView` is in `browser.xml`.

I has omitted some code , but it still long...

So , maybe someone can teach me the direction.

Question is:

Why the check imageview set the `setVisibility` to `VISIBLE` , but it doesn't show the on item of `Gridview`.

Does the `check image` possible be obstruct by upper image ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AstralProjection Can you explain more ? Thanks

Comment: refer this link http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/04/26/multiple-selection-listview-android/

Comment: Refer: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296